# Can I migrate an InfoPath form from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint Online classic teamsite?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, 2007

We are using 3 infopath forms in SharePoint 2007. We would like to migrate all SharePoint 2007 sites to SharePoint Online by migration tooling. I expect the migration tooling will not migrate this infopath forms. So I would like to that by my self. Can I export an infopath form from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are main five steps for migrating on-premise infopath form to SharePoint online:

1. Get the form template from the originating list
2. Change the format to CAB file and extract the contents
3. Modify manifest file
4. Zip the file in the XSN format
5. Republish the resulting file to the new list

See below article for details:
[enter link description here](http://www.sharepointjunkies.com/migrate-infopath-forms-sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-online/)

Besides,you could choose Microsoft PowerApps as alternative from this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/migrate-infopath-forms-to-sharepoint).